# Get a boolean value from DataTable

Tags: c#, .net-1.1

How do I retrieve a Boolean value in dataset, I'm using visual studio 2003,I am trying the following, but it's not working:

```
//if product inactive, don't display, and redirect to main page
  if((dbDataSet.Tables["productGeneral"].Rows[0]["Active"].Equals(0)))
```

I even tried, but not working:

```
if((dbDataSet.Tables["productGeneral"].Rows[0]["Active"].toString() == false)
```

the columns name is ["active"], the value with in column is either True or False, using sql server 2000

please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast to a bool directly, and just check using that.

Have you tried?:

```
if(((bool)dbDataSet.Tables["productGeneral"].Rows[0]["Active"] == false))
```

If it's a bool, you'll want to cast the result to a bool directly.

The first fails since 0 is an Int32, not a Boolean.  They are not comparable in C#, since they're distinct types.  The second fails since ToString() turns the result into a string, and you're comparing a string to a bool, which again will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following

```
   if (Convert.ToBoolean(dbDataSet.Tables["productGeneral"].Rows[0]["Active"]) == true)
   {}
```