# get boolean value from selected row of datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, selectbooleancheckbox, fullrowselect

i am trying to select the bit value of sql which is present in the grid when trying to access its just giving error.

protected void ProductGrid_SelectedIndex(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            PRID.Text=RequisitionGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;

```
        vid.Text=RequisitionGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;

        vaddress.Text=RequisitionGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;

        BrandID.Text=RequisitionGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text;

        prodID.Text=RequisitionGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text;

        quantity.Text=RequisitionGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text;

        description.Text=RequisitionGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text;

        date.Value = RequisitionGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[8].Text;
  approvecheck.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(RequisitionGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[9]);             
    }
```

i also tried

approvecheck.Checked = (RequisitionGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text == "1");

it does not give error but yet no response to the checkbox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a boolean value from DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050663/get-a-boolean-value-from-datatable)

Comment: that method is for dataset i am using datatable

Comment: It’s applied in the same way, have you tried directly casting to bool?

Comment: help me how i dont know how to do it directly when i tried this method to insert into sql it worked but doent work backwards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a boolean value from DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050663/get-a-boolean-value-from-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

Try directly casting the cell to a bool instead of converting it.

```cs
approvecheck.Checked = ((bool)RequisitionGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[9]);
```

Comment: What is the error? can you tell me what the value of the cell is? It makes it harder to help when we have less information to go on

Comment: cell is 9 as you can see in the code but the suggestion you gave is not even compiling

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask for the content of the cell, not the index

Comment: Please can you tell us the error you get when it won’t compile.